# Campos para inserção de dados no formulario

Tags: javascript, html

Ola gostaria de fazer um metodo onde o usuario clica no input e sempre direcionar para o ultimo caracter digitado, alguma dica?

Comment: Queres fazer isso quando o utilizador seleciona o input (no evento `focus`?)

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Com base nesta pergunta do stackEN, você pode fazer como o código abaixo.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609405/set-focus-after-last-character-in-text-box

```
(function($){
    $.fn.setCursorToTextEnd = function() {
        var $initialVal = this.val();
        this.val($initialVal);
    };
})(jQuery);


$('#meuTXT').setCursorToTextEnd();
```